# Buffer Overflow

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

I am trying to overflow the buffer shown bellow, yet can never reach it. I know that the location of buf is before i and len, and in my case to overload the return instruction I need to amend the integer len. I know I need to fill in the buffer till I get to the len variable, but don't know how to avoid filling the i variable without screwing up the counter.

I've tried filling the input string with just a bunch of NOP but that automatically overflows the variable i with 0x909, when I try to change it and just fill it with numbers from 0 to 272 it makes it go into a loop and changes back to a number in the loop.

```
int function( char *input)
{
    char    buf[256];
    int i, len;

    if (strlen(input) > 272) {
         len = 272;
    } else {
        len = strlen(input);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        buf[i] = arg[i];
    }
    return (0);
}

int
lab_main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    foo ( argv[1] );
}
```

Comment: What architecture is this? What flags did you use to compile and what protections are enabled?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
There is a bug in the code.

```
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        buf[i] = arg[i];
    }
```

The variable `arg` is not defined, not sure how this would even compile. It should probably be `input`.

---

Try the following;

```
./a.out $(python -c "print 'A'*272")
```

I have not tried this myself, but it should overflow the return address on the stack. Since the buffer itself is 256 bytes, the two integers are 4 bytes each and the saved base pointer is 4 bytes. This gives us 256+4+4+4 = 268, which leaves 4 bytes for the return address. If you run the command you should see that you either corrupt a stack canary or overflow the return address and attempt to return to 0x41414141.

Actually getting arbitrary code execution after that is a different story, and depends entirely on the mitigations of the target system/binary file.

Answer (score 0):

`i` and `len` would often be registers, and therefore unaffected by your memory copying. If they are in fact being loaded from (and stored to, in `i`'s case) on every iteration, though, you just need to set the correct bytes in your input buffer such that the value that gets written to `i` is the one that should be written. Assuming you're on x86 or another little-endian system, you will write the least-significant to most-significant bytes, which makes it easy to make a small edit. Assuming you're running into `i` before `len`, you can probably just write a value to `i` that makes the loop skip ahead a few bytes to the part of `len` you want to overwrite, overwrite it, and then continue on to your saved return address or whatever else you're targeting. You could also overwrite `i` with the correct values until you get to the most significant byte, which you could then make negative; this will pass the loop condition but also likely send you quite far off in the address space, plausibly into kernel space (which will cause an exception). If `len` comes before `i` in the variables that get overwritten, you can put an immense value into `len` and then write a value into `i` that jumps to wherever you want to be, without it needing to be contiguous with or even close to the buffer.